# Why is custom image for tab bar item so poor?

Tags: icons, xcode7, uitabbar, swift2

[image][image][image]

"Pika" and "Pikachu" is custom images. How come they are so poor comparing to the "Downloads" tab bar item icon which is from the system? The images is png and a resolution about 25x25px. I have tried differents resolution but all give this poor view.  Hope you guys can help - Thank you.

Comment: "About 25x25", or exactly? If your image is not the exact same size as the bounding box then you'll want to make it precisely the same.

Comment: @l'L'l it is exactly. Got it from this website https://icons8.com/web-app/category/ios7/Baby

Comment: How it's bounding box dimensions in the size inspector? If it's any larger/smaller then the image will distort. It looks like you maybe should use a higher resolution image (perhaps 32x32 and up)

Comment: @l'L'l see my edited answer. The settings is for "Pika"

Comment: Settings look ok although which device are you viewing it on?

Comment: For that device you should have the resolution at 50x50 (@2x). Refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the [Icon and Image Sizes Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) for the device you are building for the result should work as expected. In this case you would likely want to use 50x50 (@2x) image sizes if you are creating a UITabBar for the iPhone 5:

[image]

Using this the appropriate sized icons should yeild nice sharp icons when the project is built:

[image]

Comment: 1x, 2x. 3x, which resolution should the different png image be? Or is it enough just to make a 50x50 and drag n drop in all tree  container?

Comment: Typically you would want each size 50x50 (1x), 100x100 (2x), 150x150 (3x). Since the UITabBar at (@1x) is normally 25x25, providing the 50x50 which is (@2x) should be adequate if your target is an iPhone 5. If you need to support higher resolution devices then you'll want to consider creating higher res versions.

Comment: I need to taget all iPads and iPhones. How should my image set then be? Thanks again

Comment: Did you look at the Icon Guidelines?? The information is all there. You'll want slightly higher resolution for newer iPhones, and iPad Pro. Usually you can tell if your images are going to look ok if you try out it out in the simulator. There are also quite a few apps which are freely available that can do resizing automatically.

Comment: Great instruction. A correction: looks like you need 25, 50, and 75 (not 50, 100, and 150). Among other things, it will allow you to stay without Icons8's freemium limit.